# Why is this C program filling drive C:\?

Tags: compression, c, winrar

The code below is a C program that compresses some. They are sharing folders, and some have around 6G. But the C: / drive has only 4G free, today, and every time the script runs it loads, I believe it's because of temporary files.

But I've already changed the folder for temporary files in Winrar to Options> Settings> Path> Folder for temporary files: "E: \ temp".

What could be happening? See, the code is basically this (some snippets, where you just change the directory to be compressed, removed to be summarized):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    char comando [150]={""};

    char ano [3];
    char mes [3];
    char dia[3];
    char data[15] ={""};
    char pasta[15] = {""};
    char *Pont_Pasta = pasta;

    unsigned long tempo_Espera = 100000;

    time_t t = time(0);
    struct tm * now = localtime (& t);
    sprintf(ano,"%i",now->tm_year+1900);
    sprintf(mes,"%i",now->tm_mon+1);
    sprintf(dia,"%i",now->tm_mday);

    strcat(data,"_");
    strcat(data,ano);
    strcat(data,"_");
    strcat(data,mes);
    strcat(data,"_");
    strcat(data,dia);

 strcat(comando,"start c:\\arquiv~1\\winrar\\rar a E:\\backup\\aquisicao\\aquisicao");strcat(comando,data);strcat(comando,".rar E:\\aquisicao");
    system(comando);
    strcpy(comando,"");
    _sleep(tempo_Espera);

 (...)

 return 0;    
}
```

---

@phuclv I didn't create this code, but I understand that strcp is for clearing the string command. As for the date lines, I left it like this:

```
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
char data[30];

time (&rawtime);
timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);

strftime(data,30,"_%Y%m%d",timeinfo);
```

Comment: this is off topic. Anyway your code has so many redundant `strcpy`s. Shouldn't it be easier and faster to do `sprintf(data, "%d_%d_%d", now->tm_year+1900, now->tm_mon+1, now->tm_mday);`. Then what's the point of `strcpy(comando,"");`?

Answer (score 1):

The command line `RAR.EXE` that is called by the `C` program doesn't use the `temp-files` setting from the `WinRAR.EXE` GUI program.
You need to specify the temp-folder for RAR.EXE using a command-line parameter.
I don't have a copy of WinRAR at my disposal but `RAR -h` or `RAR -?` should give you the information which parameter to use.

Comment: None of rar.exe v5.71's options appear to change the temporary compression directory. This [link](http://www.winrarrepair.net/winrar-temp-folder-windows-10.html) tells how to change the user's temporary directory. While performing a computer test at home I didn't notice my user's tmp folder increase in compression process. It may not be the compression process that is increasing C: \ during script execution.